# Geometrical meaning of intersection between line and bundle of circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the following bundle of circles:

$$x^2(1 + k) + y^2(1 + k) + x(24 + 8k) + y(-4 -4k) + 4k + 132$$

I would have to find the circles tangent to the x-axis.

The way I would solve this is: plug $0$ into the $y$ variable (intersect the bundle with the x-axis), solve the resulting second degree equation and again solve for $k$ by forcing the discriminant to $0$.

I don't understand why, however, this method works; I would never solve a problem by using a method I don't understand.

Intersecting the bundle of circles with the x-axis gives us a second degree equation, which is a parabola (a bundle of parabolas, actually). 
Now, generally, forcing the discriminant of a second degree equation to zero really means limiting the solutions to when they are only one and not two; more clearly, it means we're looking for only one intersection point.

Geometrically, on a graph, what does it mean to force the discriminant of the above equation to zero?

What does the (bundle of) parabola we found before represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

$$
x^2 (1 + k) + y^2 (1 + k) + x (24 + 8 k) - 4y (1 + k) + 4 k + 132=0
$$

The intersection with $y = \mu$ is obtained by solving for $x$

$$
x^2 (1 + k) + \mu^2 (1 + k) + x (24 + 8 k) - 4\mu (1 + k) + 4 k + 132=0
$$

or

$$
x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{-(k (\mu -6)+\mu +2) (k (\mu +2)+\mu -6)}-4 k-12}{k+1}
$$

but at tangency

$$
(k (\mu -6)+\mu +2) (k (\mu +2)+\mu -6) = 0
$$

then

$$
k (\mu -6)+\mu +2=0 \ \ \mbox{or}\ \ k (\mu +2)+\mu -6 = 0
$$

but we need the tangency when $\mu = 0$ then

$$
-6k +2=0 \ \ \mbox{or}\ \ 2k -6 = 0
$$

giving

$$
k = \frac 13\ \ \mbox{and} \ \ k = 3
$$

Attached a plot showing the circles bundle (light blue) and  in red the circle for $k = \frac 13$

[image]

NOTE

The circles's bundle can be written as

$$
\left(x+\frac{4 (k+3)}{k+1}\right)^2+(y-2)^2=\left(4\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)^2
$$

Comment: Which I am aware of. My question was, however, why do you solve for $x$, what does it geometrically mean since we're dealing with a parabola?

Comment: First we find the intersection between the generic circle and a line parallel to the $x$ axis which is $y = \mu$ Secondly we  impose that this intersection be a tangency, with only an outcome for $x$. This implies on the null discriminant and Thirdly, we choose $\mu = 0$ Those are the geometric facts.